# US immigration and I-94 and passport issues

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, esta, i-94

I hold a Singapore passport. Earlier this year, I travelled to the US under the VWP. I entered and exited the US through SFO by air after about 10 days. I tried to check my I-94 status and my travel history through the official CBP portal. I encountered a few issues:

- My I-94 record just shows the entry date (i.e. the day I arrived in SFO) and NOT the exit date.
- When i clicked on the "get this travelers travel history", the system  simply says "NO RECORD FOUND"

Will this cause any problems when I try to re-enter the US? This was done on my old passport where my full name was reflected without the indication of which is the SURNAME or FIRSTNAME(i.e. the MRZ had something like HOWARD<JOHN<LEE) ": (my surname is HOWARD) so in reality the I-94 record is FNU HOWARD JOHN LEE.

During my us trip, I briefly went to Canada and came back through the land border. I had some issues trying to re-enter where the CBP officer could not find my I-94 record (I presume this is because of the confusion of which combination of names the CBP officer who admitted me used to register in the system) and I had to go inside and get it manually verified.

Upon my return from the trip, I immediately applied for a new passport and got my name properly reflected this time round. E.g. HOWARD<<JOHN<LEE. I understand this voids the ESTA i used to have (tied to the old passport number).

My main concern here is will I face any issues when I return to visit the US as my I-94 does not have a record of the departure and I cannot retrieve the traveler history and I'm travelling on a different passport this time (name is the same but its just the indication of the surname and passport number which is different).

What should I do in such a situation? I have tried searching but the CBP website and their enquiry email is not very helpful. Thank You.

Comment: The officers can see your entry and departure dates based on your passport details. It is not uncommon to have trouble with the I-94 website. Your new ETSA will give the officers everything they need to process you. You shouldn't have any trouble if you depart and arrive legally. They can verify you and won't need any I-94 from you.

Comment: In the worst case, if they do not know when you left the US, just present evidence that you left the US (e.g. flight ticket) or entered another country after your departure date (e.g. an entry stamp to another country, or receipts or other things that place you in another country)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are unlikely to have any trouble. Having no I-94 record is not uncommon, it happens (unrelated to your name). You'll be flying in I presume, so obviously you've left, so they'll issue a new I-94. You will need to renew your ESTA.

The no I-94 record issue happened to my wife last month. After three entries into the US where they spent several minutes each time trying to find it (but allowing her in anyway) they just issued her a new I-94.

BTW they don't type in your name, it's pulled automatically from the passport when they scan it.